# Change image onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display a different image when clicking on my image. A demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sj7o9x58/). When clicking on the image the image should change to an arrow pointing up instead of pointing down. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
    <div id="flip"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/YCf5zYt.png"></div>
    <div id="panel" style="display: none;"><p><i><strong>CONTENT</strong></i></p>
    </div>
</td>
```

JS

```
var toggled = false;
$("img").click(function () {
    if (!toggled) {
        $(this).css("", "url(http://i.imgur.com/YCf5zYt.png)");
        toggled = true;
    } else {
        $(this).css("", "url(http://i.imgur.com/V4fKMWS.png)");
        toggled = false;
    }

    $("p").slideToggle();
})
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flip").click(function () {
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding background image to button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351283/adding-background-image-to-button)

Comment: Check `console(F12)` for errors..

Comment: Just change `img` tag attribute `src`: https://jsfiddle.net/sj7o9x58/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another solution with `toggleClass()` and `attr()` function :

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dz8t4tta/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){          
          $(this).attr("src","http://i.imgur.com/V4fKMWS.png");
        } else {    
          $(this).attr("src","http://i.imgur.com/YCf5zYt.png");
        }   
        $("#panel").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with the code:

First of all, you have to attach all of the event handlers from within the document ready callback. As it stands right now, it is possible that event handler is not attached because image tag may be not yet loaded when you try to attach the handler.

You also have to modify the `src` attribute of the image, not the css's `url` style:

```
$(this).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/YCf5zYt.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the attribue src.

```
 if (!toggled) {
            $(this).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/YCf5zYt.png");
            toggled = true;
        } else {
            $(this).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/V4fKMWS.png");
            toggled = false;
        }
```

Refer link: https://jsfiddle.net/sj7o9x58/2/

Answer (score 1):

there a mistakes in your code try this

```
  var toggled = false;
       $("img").click(function () {
    if (!toggled) {
        $(this).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/YCf5zYt.png");
        toggled = true;
    } else {
        $(this).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/V4fKMWS.png");
        toggled = false;
    }

    $("p").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to write all your code in `$(document).ready();` And you have a big mistake.
You should use `.slideToggle()` for `$("#panel")`. And this is easier way to do it(without any variables):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        if($("#panel").css("display") === "none"){
            $("#panel").slideToggle().css("display", "block");
            $("img").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/V4fKMWS.png");
    }   else if($("#panel").css("display") === "block"){
            $("#panel").slideToggle();
            $("img").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/YCf5zYt.png");
    }
    });
});
```

And demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DimonLuk/2oeuf6xg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var toggled = true;

    $("img").on('click',function () {
        if (!toggled) {
            $(this).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/YCf5zYt.png");
            toggled = true;
        } else {
            $(this).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/V4fKMWS.png");
            toggled = false;
        }

        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

The updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sj7o9x58/3/

I don't know if that's the image behavior you want, if it's the oposite just change te toggled initialization to *false* and the image by default on the src (html).